# Add custom column or edit column type in POWER BI ONLINE

Tags: powerbi

I am importing data on a daily basis from a CSV file into PowerBI online (NOT DESKTOP!). I need to manipulate one column for it to become a date column

I don't see the option to EDIT QUERY, like there is in PowerBI Desktop

This is a sample of the value in the column: April 01 2019, 01:00
It is now treated as text, I would like to convert it to date.

Maybe someone has an idea how to achieve it?

I cannot use PowerBI Desktop for this and I cannot manipulate the file itself manually every day..

Comment: I have adapted the mechanism and now I have linked the CSV into another excel file, there I do my manipulations and I link this excel file to PowerBI instead. This works. The PowerBI has an autorefresh. However, my question is If I will not open the excel file, will it automatically take fresh data from the CSV file, when it autorefreshes the PowerBI?

Comment: What's the problem with [dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-create-use)? Transform your data there.